# Backbone model.save returning error while server sending 200:OK

Tags: backbone.js

I have defined the following Backbone Model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "/login",
        contentType: "application/com.example.auth+json",

        defaults: {
            userName: '',
            password: ''
        },

        validate: function(attrs){
            if(!attrs.userName){
                return 'Please fill username field.'
            }
            if(!attrs.password){
                return 'Please fill password field.'
            }
        }
    });
```

I am using the following code in my Backbone.View

```
// ... 
   initialize: function() {    
       this.model = new User();
       myUser = {
           userName: 'labuser1@example.com',
           password: 'abcd_1234',
       };
    }

    onSubmit: function() {

        this.model.save(myUser, {
            success: function () {
                alert('You are authenticated');
                Backbone.trigger('Authenticated', {source: 'LOGIN'});
            },
            error: function (model, error) {
                alert('Error: " + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

I am receiving the following response from backend, no response data is send only status code is returned:

```
Request URL : https://server/login

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK
```

But I am getting 'Error: [object Object]' printed. Why it is not reaching success handler, inspite of the server authenticating the user successfully. Please advise how to fix this in frontend / backend if required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either use this code `dataType: 'text'` to fix it

```
...
this.model.save(myUser, {
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function () {
...
```

or fix server side by setting correct `Content-type` header to `application/json` value.

Comment: thanks, I added code dataType: 'text' and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Update `initialize` to :

```
    initialize: function() {    
      var myUser = {
           userName: 'labuser1@example.com',
           password: 'abcd_1234',
       };
      this.model = new User(myUser);
    }
```

You need to initialize your `model` hereand then in 
`onSubmit` function you can directly save it  :

```
onSubmit: function() {

        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function () {
                alert('You are authenticated');
                Backbone.trigger('Authenticated', {source: 'LOGIN'});
            },
            error: function (model, error) {
                alert('Error: " + error);
            }
        });
    }
```

NOTE : `model.save` should be used to create a new model and persist it at backend and not to authenticate. You might want to make a different ajax call for this.

Comment: Hello Niranjan, thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for the typos, have corrected them now. please relook at my code again.

Comment: i am doing as described in your reply, still i am getting the same error. Can this be a problem with a backend service? If yes any idea what exactly we need to change to get this working.

Comment: @tarun_telang What does your login service return?

Comment: the service returns no response data. it just return HTTP status 200 as described above.

Comment: For services returning JSON object, I am encountering problem in Windows 8.1. I was able to see Backbone.model.save()'s success callback getting executed in older OS (Windows 7 for all browsers). Where as applications keeps waiting in Windows 8.1 when run with any browsers even with response type Header set to  application/json by Backend Server.
after tring out various options of saving Backbone.Model and analysis, I found that adding dataType: 'text' and then converting the response to JSON.parse(response) solves my problem which I was facing in Windows 8.1. Please update your experiences ?

Answer (score 1):

In case of PUT (model update) make sure to return status 204 (no-content) instead of 200 (ok) if your response does not contain any content.