# PHP Cross Domain (AJAX) Proxy with Backbone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Here is the problem I am facing.

I am building my rest api with Laravel 4 on domain A.

The api will supply JSON's to my app which is on domain B.

To avoid cross origin policy problems I have done two things:

1. Client side - I have downloaded a PHP proxy script - on domain B - and use it to send GET, POST requests to my api on domain A.

I've used the script located here, on [github](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy).

1. Serve side, I have enabled Laravel to accept CORS.

All is well, things are "sort-of" working.

The front end is controlled by Backbone, which leads me to the source of my problem.

Looking at the proxy's docs, here is how it should be used with jQuery:

```
$('#target').load('http://www.yourdomain.com/proxy.php', {
    csurl: 'http://www.cross-domain.com/',
    param1: value1,
    param2: value2
});
```

Basically, I send a **csurl** with the value of my REST Api domain - domainA

The other params (param1 and param2) are used to send different things to the api, **like the csrf token and so on**.

Getting over to Backbone, I can't seem to make the Backbone model work properly and I'm not sure how to handle sending the params.

Here is the backbone model:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://domainB.dev/proxy.php'
});
```

In my view, I instantiate it and try to pass the parameters:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.save({
    data: {
        csurl: 'http://domainA.dev'
        param1: 'mytoken'
    }
}, {
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

The data does not reach my api - I find it in the post, the post actually works - but I don't get a success callback.

**Basically, I don't know how to implement the proxy's docs into a Backbone.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the same problem as here

[Backbone model.save returning error while server sending 200:OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181133/backbone-model-save-returning-error-while-server-sending-200ok/21205808#21205808)

I reviewed proxy.php script and didn't find any header for json content type. So again:
You can either use this code dataType: 'text' to fix it

```
myModel.save(
    {
        data: {
            csurl: 'http://domainA.dev'
            param1: 'mytoken'
        }
    },
    {
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(){},
        error: function(){}
    }
);
```

...
or fix server side by setting correct `Content-type` header to `application/json` value.

Comment: Hey Eugene, ty! - I have checked - Laravel (which holds my api, server side) sends the correct JSON header - I've inspected it looking at the response directly in my browser. The problem is the proxy script, I believe, which changes the header into "text/html" - now, I've added the dataTpe text to my backbone model and it still isnt' working

Comment: I had to configure the proxy script and add the server's url, in order for the script to allow it. Now, I get a valid JSON response with the right headers, but Backbone's success callback does not fire. Which is really weird. Any ideas?

Comment: I've no ideas, in such cases I use debugger :-)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to remove url parameter in your model.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Then create a collection.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    url: 'http://domainB.dev/proxy.php',
    parse: function(data) {
        return data;
    }
});
```

After that, replace your view code with this one

```
var that = this;
formData = {
    csurl: 'http://domainA.dev',
    param1: 'mytoken'
}
this.collection = new MyCollection();
this.collection.save({
    data: formData,
    success: function(collection, response) {
        console.log(that.collection);
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
}, {});
```

Comment: Ty Dato' - from what I've seen, basically I will be doing the save through a collection instead of the model - why do you think it will work? Can you explain your answer as to why it is different?